# Escaping double quotes while rendering in Jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, escaping, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 to create Golang code using Python3. I need to pass some parameters in quotes to a function in my final code, but Jinja2 isn't escaping double quotes.
My python code is something like:

```
list_s = ['a', 'b']
string = '\"' + '", "'.join(list_s) + '\"'
final_string = 'Function(' + string + ')'
print(final_string)

template.render({'function': final_string})
```

My template is:

```
e.({{function}})
```

What I'm getting in the console (the print in the python code):

```
Function("a", "b")
```

What I wanted in my final code in Go:

```
e.(Function("a", "b"))
```

What I'm actually getting in my final code:

```
e.(Function(&#34;a&#34;, &#34;b&#34;))
```

I've already tried:

```
'`\"`' , '`"`', "'\"'", "\\\"", "\N{Quotation Mark}"
```

And none of them worked as I wanted. Any ideas?

Thank you :))

**"Solved":**

I changed from double quotes to `, so my python code now is:

```
string = '`' + '`, `'.join(list_s) + '`'
```

And my final Go code is:

```
e.(Function(`a`, `b`))
```

And this works on Go. It isn't the best solution but it is working...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The alternative way to do this would have been

```
e.({{ function|safe }})
```

which prevents auto-escaping.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Jinja2 autoescaping. As described in [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#controlling-autoescaping), the recommended way to avoid this is to wrap the text in a `Markup` object.