# Jinja templating javascript variables

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass a list from flask into my javascript and then iterate over it when the user presses enter. For example I send a list from python into the rendered template as `["a","b","c"]` and then in my rendered template I want to acces it as `{{ list[0] }}` for the first element which would be "a" and display it in a div, then when the user presses enter I want to change the text in the div to the one of `{{ list[1] }}` and so on until the end of the list (let's say `{{ list[n] }}`

So far I have tried creating a counter and incrementing it by 1 every time the user presses enter in order to switch the index value of the list, however it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
    var cont = 0;
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            cont ++;
            document.getElementById("divtochange").innerHTML = '{{ "%s%s%s"|format("list[", cont, "]") }}';

        }
    });
</script>
```

If I input manually `{{ list[0] }}` or any other index I get the corresponding value, however I want it to change every time I press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template only gets evaluated when the page loads, so what the browser sees at that point is essentially static content. You need to pass the dynamic elements into JavaScript so that it can manipulate them while the user is interacting with the page.

I'm no Javascript programmer, but something like

```
<script>
    var cont = 0;
    var list = {{list | safe}};
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            cont ++;
            document.getElementById("divtochange").innerHTML = list[cont];
        }
    });
</script>
```

(Added the `|safe` based on comments.)

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'` because jinja is rendering my list into the template as `[&#39;a&#39;, &#39;a&#39;, &#39;c&#39;]` it is switching the " characters from the string type. This doesn't happen if I use '{{ list }}' only if I use {{ list }}

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852574/escaping-double-quotes-while-rendering-in-jinja2 for how to fix that.  Updated answer.